# How to create model and add Json response to model in swift?

Tags: json, swift, model

I need to create model for Json response, but i am unable to do

how to create model and use that model variable in other viewcontroller

```
 {
"jsonrpc": "2.0",
"result": {
    "userdata": {
        "id": 47,
        "fname": "sample",
        "lname": "test",
        "slug": "sample-test",
        "email": "tom1@gmail.com",
        "email_verified_at": "2021-02-17 20:34:17",
    },
    "token": "eyJ0eXAiOiJKV1QiLCJhbGciOiJIUzI1NiJ9.eyJzdWIiOjQ3LCJpc3MiOiJodHRwczovL2FwcGxlc2tvb2wuY29tL3ByZXZpZXcvYXBwbGVza29cyLCJuYmYiOjE2MTQwMTI3NzIsImp0aSI6Iktub2x4R3l2M2JEUVozUXAifQ.jjvMYGywY_85saSHPzEhvFD2__hGRa_AsbRj1S3rRXw"
}
}
```

i have tried like below:

```
class LoginUserData: NSObject {

var id: Int?
var fname: String?
var lname: String?
var slug: String?
var email: String?

init(id: Int, fname: String, lname: String, slug: String, email: String) {
    
    self.id = id
    self.fname = fname
    self.lname = lname
    self.slug = slug
    self.email = email
}
}
```

but in loginservice i am unable to add data to model:

```
var loginData: LoginUserData?


do {
let json = try JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: data, options: []) as? [String:Any]
print("the json output \(String(describing: json))")

let error = json!["error"] as? [String : Any]

let status = error?["status"] as? [String : Any]
                
DispatchQueue.main.sync{
if error != nil{
}
else{
    let res = json?["result"] as? [String : Any]
    let uData = res?["userdata"] as? [String : Any]
    
    self.loginData?.email = uData?["email"] as? String
    
    print("nsoblject email: \(self.loginData?.email)") // here getting nil
    
}
}
```

`self.loginData?.email = uData?["email"] as? String` getting nil, how to use `loginData?.email` in other viewcontroller? please do help

Comment: You never did `loginData = LoginUserData.init(...)`. It should be `if let emailAsString = uData?["email"] as String, let idAsInt = uData?["id"] as? Int, ... { self.loginData = LoginUserData.init(id: idAsInt, lname: ...) }` 
Note that in Swift 4+ you can use Codable instead.

Comment: @Larme i am using codable for json request.. can i use codable for response? how? can u pls post the answer pls?

Comment: if i do `if let emailAsString = uData?["email"] as String` then its coming.. but i need to use login email in other viewcontroller... how?

Answer (score 1):

First the json has syntax error. Remove the last "," after

`"email_verified_at": "2021-02-17 20:34:17",`

So it should be

```
"email_verified_at": "2021-02-17 20:34:17"
```

Next,

I will recommend you use struct model for your json. struct are value types, whereas class are reference type. Basically, struct are easier to work it.

I will say create your jSon Model using Codable as:

```
// MARK: - Welcome
struct LoginUserData: Codable {
    let jsonrpc: String
    let result: Result
}

// MARK: - Result
struct Result: Codable {
    let userdata: Userdata
    let token: String
}

// MARK: - Userdata
struct Userdata: Codable {
    let id: Int
    let fname, lname, slug, email: String
    let emailVerifiedAt: String

    enum CodingKeys: String, CodingKey {
        case id, fname, lname, slug, email
        case emailVerifiedAt = "email_verified_at"
    }
}
```

And then you can decode the jSon as:

```
  var loginData: LoginUserData?


do {
      let decoder = JSONDecoder()
      let json = try decoder.decode(LoginUserData.self, from: data)
      
      DispatchQueue.main.async {

          self.loginData?.email = json.result.userdata.email
          print("nsoblject email: \(self.loginData?.email)")

      }
  }
```